# Erro ao instalar Visual Studio 2013 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Boa Noite!

Fiz o download do Visual Studio 2013 Community no sistema operacional Windows 7, quando executo o mesmo apresenta a mensagem:

`SETUP BLOCKED`

Lembrando que eu já tenho Windows 7 SP1 e Internet Explorer 10 instalados. Porém o erro persiste, por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema porque minha versão do windows 7 era muito antiga,
ativei as atualizações automática, apareceu algumas atualizações, eu atualizei e funcionou.

Recomendo que você faça as atualizações do Windows.

Answer (score 0):

O Visual Studio 2013 funciona apenas em máquinas com Windows 8 ou Windows Server 2012 instalado. Veja a tabela detalhada [aqui](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx).

Utilize o Visual Studio 2012, que é compatível com Windows 7.

Comment: [De acordo com o link ofical do VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-community-vs#sysreqs) funciona em win7 também, mas o sp 1.

Comment: eu tenho rodando tanto o 2013 quanto o 2015 no windows 7

Comment: Windows 8 só é obrigatório para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos para o Windows Store e Windows Phone